# What is the pagerank of the given nodes?

Tags: algorithms

Given nodes $A,B$ and $C$. with $A \rightarrow A$, $A\rightarrow B$, $B \rightarrow B$, $C \rightarrow A$, $C \rightarrow C$ where the arrows represent outgoing links from left and incoming links to the node on the right. I'm supposed to find the pagerank of each of the nodes.

My solution: Using the formula PR(i)= $\sum_{j\in B_u}$ $\frac{PR(j)}{L(j)}$
and assuming that each node initial outgoing link has $0.25$ value:

> $PR(A)= \frac{0.25}{2} + \frac{0.25}{2} = 0.25$
>
> $PR(B)= \frac{0.25}{2} = 0.125$
>
> $PR(C)= 0$

Where I'm stuck:

1. In $L(j)$ do I count the returning links also as out-going links? In my answer I have considered them.
2. When there are no incoming links is the $PR$ of that node $0$ or is initial_value+incoming_links_value? As in node $C$.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $B_u$? What is $L()$?

Comment: @oks $B_u$ is the set of incoming links to node i. L(j) is the number of outgoing links from node j.